# Numeric and percentage deadband calculation

Tags: php

Calculate if the value exceeds percentage <> numeric deadbands of the previous value.

The first function is for percentage. It detects if `$value` is `$deadband%` greater or less than $previous.

The second is for numeric difference. It detects if the difference between `$value` and `$previous` is greater than `$deadband`.

```
function percentage_deadband($value,$previous,$deadband)
{
    if($previous==0 || $value==0 || $previous == $value)
    {
        return false; //if previous or value is 0, we can't work. assume false.
    }
    $percentage = $value / $previous * 100;
    if($percentage > 100){
        return $percentage - $deadband > 100;//if percentage - deadband > 100, we know the deadband is exceeded
    }
    if($percentage < 100){
        return 100 - $percentage > $deadband;//if 100 - percentage is greater than deadband, we know the deadband is exceeded
    }
    return false;
}


function numeric_deadband($value,$previous,$deadband)
{
    if($previous==0 || $value==0 || $previous == $value)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if($previous > $value){
        return $previous - $deadband >= $value;
    }else{
        return $value - $previous >= $deadband;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Testing the functions**

```
$numeric_deadband = 3;
$numeric_set = [
    0=>['value'=>77,'previous'=>80],//true
    1=>['value'=>78,'previous'=>77],//false
    2=>['value'=>81,'previous'=>78],//true
    3=>['value'=>81,'previous'=>81]//false
];
echo '<strong>numeric set:</strong><br/>';
foreach($numeric_set as $row)
{

    var_dump(numeric_deadband($row['value'],$row['previous'],$numeric_deadband));
    echo '<br/>';
}

echo '<br/>';

$percentage_deadband = 10;
$percentage_set = [
    0=>['value'=>27,'previous'=>39],//true
    1=>['value'=>39,'previous'=>40],//false
    2=>['value'=>41,'previous'=>28],//true
    3=>['value'=>28,'previous'=>31]//false
];
echo '<strong>percentage set:</strong><br/>';
foreach($percentage_set as $row)
{

    var_dump(percentage_deadband($row['value'],$row['previous'],$percentage_deadband));
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

They seem to work correctly with my small set of test data, but I am not so great with math. I'd love a second opinion.

Comment: Some comments would be nice, for example, in the first function you could specify that `$n` represents `$value` as a percentage of `$previous`.

You could also remove the last `if` statement from the first function - you're returning false either way. You also might want to be more descriptive with your variable named `$n` - maybe try `$percentChange`

Comment: not really related to your question but you might want to use PHPUnit for testing in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear about what is TRUE and what is FALSE (and how you interpret it).

```
Is it FALSE = when value is greater than previous by more than deadband?
    (i.e. value > previous + deadband is NOT OK)
    (i.e. value <= previous + deadband is OK)
That's how I did it below, but if you want the opposite, change the "<" sign.
```

I would change the two functions in one, and give an extra argument (true for numeric, false for percentage):

```
    function check_deadband($value,$previous,$deadband,$check_numeric) {
        if ($value <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($check_numeric) {
           // numeric testing
            $difference=abs($previous-$value);
            return $difference < $deadband;
            // ex. value: 74, previous: 70 => difference = 4
            // difference: 4 < deadband: 3 => false, not ok
        } else {
            // percentage testing
            $percentage=abs(($value - $previous) * 100/$previous);
            return $percentage < $deadband;
            // ex. v:111 p:100, (v-p)*100/p:11% < 10% => false, not ok
        }
    }
```

You eliminated the previous=0 or previous=value cases in your example, but I didn't understand why (you can put them back).
I also not sure that your percentage formula is corect. If you want the difference in percentage, then (value-previous)*100/previous will give you the right answer. (ex. value = 10, previous=5 => percentage is 100 - correct!)
You can check the function with the following testing code:

```
    $numeric_deadband = 3;
    $percentage_deadband = 10;

    /// GENERATE RADNOM DATA ex. 5.000 rows
    $rows_nr=5000;
    $min=40;
    $max=80;
    for ($i=0; $i<$rows_nr; $i++) {
        $numeric_set[]=array(
            "value"=>rand($min,$max), 
            "previous" => rand(40,80));
        $percentage_set[]=array(
            "value"=>rand($min,$max),
            "previous" => rand(40,80));
    }

    $time=microtime(true); // just for testing purposes
    foreach ($numeric_set as $row) {
        // check NUMERIC set
        // remove echos after testing
        echo "NUMERIC >> value: $row[value] vs previous :".
            "$row[previous] (deadband: $numeric_deadband) => ";
        echo check_deadband(
            $row["value"],
            $row["previous"],
            $numeric_deadband,
            true)
            ? "true" : "false";
        echo "<br/>";
    } unset($row);

    // CHECK time in miliseconds
    echo "<p>Checking deadband for NUMERIC ($rows_nr rows) took:".
        round((microtime(true)-$time)*1000)." miliseconds</p>";

    $time=microtime(true);
    foreach ($percentage_set as $row) {
        // check PERCENTAGE set
        // remove echo after testing
        echo "PERCENTAGE >> value: $row[value] vs previous:".
        "$row[previous]  (deadband: $percentage_deadband) => ";
        echo check_deadband(
            $row["value"],
            $row["previous"],
            $percentage_deadband,
            false)
            ? "true" : "false";
        echo "<br/>";
    } unset($row);

    echo "<p>Checking deadband for PERCENTAGE ($rows_nr rows) took:".
        round((microtime(true)-$time)*1000)." miliseconds</p>";
```

Hope this works. Feedback would be appreciated!

**EDIT**:
Changed the script to detect both above and below deadband changes.

Comment: it needs to detect both greater than previous by deadband and less than previous by deadband.

Comment: See modified script - it detects both cases.